# how to calculate sum of string in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb I want to calculate sum of `partialAmount` field which is of `string` type and in this field values are stored as **"20,00"**,**"15,00"**.

How to calculate sum of all values. Both of the queries I have tried are returning 0.

```
collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      sum: { $sum: "$$partialAmount" }
    }
  }
]);
```

**And:**

```
collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalAmount: {
        $sum: {
          $toDouble: "$partialAmount"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: from which number comma will start coming in partialAmount?
is there may be the case that except comma any other character may come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first query is obviously not going to work cause you're trying to sum strings, and also you have an extra "$" in "$$partialAmount".

Your second query would work if your partialAmount-s were stored in the format "15.00" and "20.00", see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TxvJjzdqehp).

If they are saved as "15,00" and "20,00" in the db, your second query should throw an error, not return 0. (If you are actually getting a zero result, then maybe your "partialAmount" field is misspelled in the db, or the field gets lost in a previous stage of the pipeline)

In this case you need either change the values in your db to the "20.00" format, or if this is not feasible, use [$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) and [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) to convert to the proper format like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/loKkyoHr60r), before converting to double and summing up the values.